# Wix toolset bootstrapper display options to chose/select msi packages to be installed

Tags: c#, .net, wix, windows-installer, wix3.11

I am creating a wix bootstrap application which contains two msi packages. Below is the code for bootstrap **bundle.wxs** file:

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Bundle Name="WixDemoSetupDefaultUI"
          Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Priom"
          UpgradeCode="7c77bd1b-fb15-46e5-9fbd-d5bf3c0f3785">

    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLargeLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
        LicenseFile="Resources/priomEula.rtf"
        ShowVersion="yes"
        LogoFile="Resources/LogoSide.png"
        ThemeFile="Resources/ClassicTheme.xml"
        LocalizationFile="Resources/ClassicTheme.wxl"/>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <Variable Name="InstallFolder" Type="string" Value="[ProgramFilesFolder]Priom Biswas" />
    <Chain>
      <MsiPackage Id="ClassLibraryMsi"
                   SourceFile="$(var.WixProjectForDemoClassLibrary.TargetDir)WixProjectForDemoClassLibrary.msi"
                   DisplayName="Demo Class Library"
                   Visible="yes">
        <MsiProperty Name="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Value="[InstallFolder]"/>
      </MsiPackage>
      <MsiPackage Id="ConsoleAppMsi"
                  SourceFile="$(var.WixProjectForDemoConsoleApp.TargetDir)WixProjectForDemoConsoleApp.msi"
                  DisplayName="Demo Console App"
                  Visible="yes">
        <MsiProperty Name="APPLICATIONFOLDER" Value="[InstallFolder]" />
      </MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
```

I am using a custom theme xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Theme xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/thmutil/2010">
  <Window Width="493" Height="320" HexStyle="100a0000" FontId="0">#(loc.Caption)</Window>
  <Font Id="0" Height="-12" Weight="500" Foreground="000000" Background="F0F0F0" >Segoe UI</Font>
  <Font Id="1" Height="-24" Weight="500" Foreground="000000">Segoe UI</Font>
  <Font Id="2" Height="-22" Weight="500" Foreground="666666" Background="F0F0F0">Segoe UI</Font>
  <Font Id="3" Height="-12" Weight="500" Foreground="000000" Background="F0F0F0" >Segoe UI</Font>
  <Font Id="4" Height="-12" Weight="500" Foreground="ff0000" Background="F0F0F0"  Underline="yes">Segoe UI</Font>
  <Font Id="5" Height="-24" Weight="500" Foreground="000000" Background="E0E0E0">Segoe UI</Font>
  <Font Id="6" Height="-9" Weight="500" Foreground="000000" Background="F0F0F0">Segoe UI</Font>
  <Font Id="7" Height="-16" Weight="500" Foreground="666666" Background="F0F0F0">Segoe UI Bold</Font>
  <Image X="0" Y="0" Width="130" Height="-45" ImageFile="logo.png" Visible="yes"/>
  <Text X="130" Y="-45" Width="500" Height="2" FontId="5" Visible="yes"></Text>
  <Page Name="Help">
    <Text X="150" Y="30" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="2" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.HelpHeader)</Text>
    <Text X="150" Y="71" Width="-20" Height="-50" FontId="6" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.HelpText)</Text>
    <Button Name="HelpCancelButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.HelpCloseButton)</Button>
  </Page>
  <Page Name="Install">
    <Text X="150" Y="15" Width="-11" Height="100" FontId="7" DisablePrefix="yes">#(loc.WillInstall)</Text>
    <Richedit Name="EulaRichedit" X="150" Y="68" Width="-11" Height="-70" TabStop="yes" FontId="0" HexStyle="0x800000" />
    <Checkbox Name="EulaAcceptCheckbox" X="-11" Y="-49" Width="246" Height="17" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.InstallAcceptCheckbox)</Checkbox>
    <Button Name="OptionsButton" X="-171" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0" HideWhenDisabled="yes">#(loc.InstallOptionsButton)</Button>
    <Button Name="InstallButton" X="-91" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.InstallInstallButton)</Button>
    <Button Name="WelcomeCancelButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.InstallCloseButton)</Button>
  </Page>
  <Page Name="Options">
    <Text X="141" Y="20" Width="-11" Height="30" FontId="2">#(loc.OptionsHeader)</Text>
    <Text X="141" Y="61" Width="-11" Height="17" FontId="3">#(loc.OptionsLocationLabel)</Text>
    <Editbox Name="FolderEditbox" X="141" Y="90" Width="-91" Height="21" TabStop="yes" FontId="3" FileSystemAutoComplete="yes" />
    <Button Name="BrowseButton" X="-11" Y="90" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="3">#(loc.OptionsBrowseButton)</Button>
    <Button Name="OptionsOkButton" X="-91" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.OptionsOkButton)</Button>
    <Button Name="OptionsCancelButton" X="-11" Y="-11" Width="75" Height="23" TabStop="yes" FontId="0">#(loc.OptionsCancelButton)</Button>
    </Page>
</Theme>
```

> I have omitted some code in the theme xml file here for better
> clarity.

What I want to achieve is **displaying the name of two msi packages** in the installation UI and chose user which msi he/she wants to install with two radio buttons or check boxes along side the name of the msi packages. Can this be achieved without creating a custom UI? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

> **Note:** Both of these msi packages have standalone functionality and none of them is a subordinate of one another. So I guess feature tree wouldn't be an option. I am using **wix 3.11**

Comment: Could you tell,  how you did the optional installation?

Answer (score 1):

As option you can write your own bootstrapper using WPF (for example) and do it via UI. [Here's great step-by-step guide how to do it](https://www.wrightfully.com/part-1-of-writing-your-own-net-based-installer-with-wix-overview/). And seems like your case is in "Quick concept overview" section.

Advantages:

1. Great UI that can be as flexible as you want.
2. Access to all processes inside bootstrapper (running of MSIs, order, working with result, log, etc.)

Disadvantages:

1. Time - unfortunately you'll need some time to implement all the stuff, design your UI and, surely, test it.